# C++ - Automatically insert a pair-like object into a map?

Tags: c++

Lets say we have some pair like class:

```
class PairLike{
public:
   string key;
   int val;
   PairLike(string Key, int Val) : key(Key), val(Val){};

   
   //...other members
};
```

A few objects to go along with it:

```
PairLike p1("a",1);
PairLike p2("b",2);
PairLike p3("c",3);
PairLike p4("d",4);
```

Is there a way of automatically working with this object?
For example, something similar to:

```
std::map<PairLike> container = {p1,p2,p3};
container.insert(p4);
```

Instead of writing something like:

```
std::map<string, int> container = {{p1.key, p1.val}, {p2.key, p2.val}, ... }
container.insert({p4.key, p4.val})
```

I'm aware that using an `std::set<PairLike>` with a comparator using `is_transparent`can achieve the result I'm looking for. However, I am curious if there is any way to approach this problem with a map.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question ... but please consider trying a Standard C++ Library "tuple": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a conversion operator for converting to `std::pair`:

```
class PairLike{
public:
   // ...

   operator std::pair<const std::string, int>() {
       return {key, val};
   }
};
```

And use it like:

```
std::map<string, int> container{p1,p2,p3};
container.insert(p4);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: please see [the @krisz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73116691/5690248) for viable alternative that I overlooked here.

---

That is not possible. `std::pair` is defined as part of the class definition, and cannot be altered to a custom class.

**P.S.** As noted by [@UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep), it's defined in [the CPP standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/map#overview-2):

```
namespace std {
  template<class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
  class map {
  public:
    // types
    using key_type               = Key;
    using mapped_type            = T;
    using value_type             = pair<const Key, T>;
    ...
```

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that this is mandated by the standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/map#overview-2 (and not just clang's implementation of the standard library)

Comment: @UnholySheep nice findings. I suspected that but never realised which part of standard it is in.